# dirInfoObj.GetFiles("*.jpg,*.png") does not return any files

Tags: c#, file-io, directoryinfo

If I do simply

```
dirInfoObj.GetFiles("*.jpg")
```

, it will return the 2 jpg's I have there. But if I try and get both jpg's and png's, like

```
dirInfoObj.GetFiles("*.jpg,*.png")
```

, it won't return anything.

Am I doing something wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the documentation for GetFiles that indicates that it supports usage of the , character like you mean it.  If you are using LINQ, you could do something like:

```
var files = dirInfoObj.GetFiles("*.jpg").Concat(dirInfoObj.GetFiles("*.png"));
```

If you need `files` to be an array, just throw a `.ToArray()` on the end.

Comment: I ended up doing a ghetto "var availExtensions = ".jpg,.gif"" then foreach file in GetFiles, compare the .Extension w/ each of these, and process if there was a match.  Oh well.  Thanks!

Comment: That's probably a more efficient way to do it anyway, especially with an arbitrarily large set of extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN entry on GetFiles

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx

states how it can be used.

It does not support a comma operator for multiple extensions.

Comment: It does state how it can be used, under the "remarks" section. It gives examples of what wildcards can be used, and how they all work out.